# How to write Sql query in laravel 5.2 to fetch data between specific interval

Tags: php, mysqli, laravel-5

i need to fetch the data from the database , the conditions are .. in my blade i had given three things for filtering. One is drop down list, from there will take deviceID , then FromDate(Fdate) and ToDate(Tdate). I need to get the data, that coming under that specific deviceID and between this two time intervel.
How can i write the sql query in laravel 5.2 for that?.
My table name is event data.

my vehicle.blade.php here am giving filtering options

```
    @extends('app')
</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
@section('content')
    <div class="templatemo-content">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="{{ url('/') }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
            <li class="active">Vehicle Detail</li>
        </ol>
        <h1>Vehicle Detail</h1>
        <p class="margin-bottom-15"></p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
                <form class="templatemo-preferences-form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/reports/vehicleReport/') }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom-15">
                            <label class="control-label">Vehicle ID</label>
                            <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('deviceID') }}" name="deviceID" >
                                @foreach( $vehicles as $vehicle)
                                    @if ($vehicle->deviceID == old('description'))
                                        <option value="{{ $vehicle->deviceID }}" selected>{{ $vehicle->description }}</option>
                                    @else
                                        <option value="{{ $vehicle->deviceID }}" >{{ $vehicle->description }}</option>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom-15">
                            <label class="control-label">From Date</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Fdate" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom-15">
                            <label class="control-label">To Date</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Tdate" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
</br></br></br></br>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                                Get Report
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </br></br></br></br>
@endsection
```

Controller Page ReportController.php

```
 <?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Faker\Provider\DateTime;
use App\User;
use App\Account;
use App\Device;
use App\Report;
use App\Http\Requests\createUserRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

class ReportController extends Controller
{
    public $type = 'Device';
    public $types = 'Report';

    public function getAdd()
    {
        $vehicles = DB::table('device')->get();
        return view('reports.vehicleDetail')->with('vehicles', $vehicles);

//        $cities = $this->getCities();
//        $types = $this->getVehicleTypes();
//        return view('pricing.add')->with(['data'=>['cities' => $cities,'types'=>$types]]);
    }


    public function Vreport(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $devices=DB::table('eventdata')-get()
                ->where("deviceID",$request['deviceID'] and timestamp  between ($request['Fdate'] and $request['Tdate']));



//            $devices = DB::table('eventdata')->get();
            return view('vehicle.vehicleAdmin')->with('devices', $devices);




        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $err) {
            //Show error page
        }

    }




}
```

Model Report.php

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Group as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
class Report extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'eventdata';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'accountID'
        ,'deviceID'
        ,'timestamp'
        ,'statusCode'
        ,'latitude'
        ,'longitude'
        ,'gpsAge'
        ,'speedKPH'
        ,'heading'
        ,'altitude'
        ,'transportID'
        ,'inputMask'
        ,'outputMask'
        ,'address'
        ,'dataSource'
        ,'rawData'
        ,'distanceKM'
        ,'geozoneIndex'
        ,'geozoneID'
        ,'creationTime'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Anyone please help.. 
Responds are appreciable..

Comment: Do you have model for event data ? what are the columns of the table ?

Comment: please include as much details as possible relating to question while posting

Comment: yes i have, i need to fetch all the column data, according to the condition which i mentioned above

Comment: ok.. could you please tell me what are the column names of the even data  table. please add code of event data modal in your question

Comment: check my answer and let me know if it works ?

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query:

```
$device_id = $request['deviceID'];
$from = $request['Fdate'];
$to = $request['Tdate'];
$devices = Report::where('deviceID',$device_id)
                   ->whereBetween('timestamp',[$from,$to])
                   ->get();
```

### Update:

`type="date"` will only provide date and no time
Source: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

> **date** :    Defines a date control (year, month and day (no time))
>   **datetime**: The input type datetime has been removed from the HTML
>   standard. Use datetime-local instead. 
> **datetime-local** : Defines a date
>   and time control (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and fraction
>   of a second (no time zone)

**Suggestion:** You should use [jQuery Date and Time picker](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/) to get the date or time input easily.

Comment: @Rahul if this solves your issue, you can mark it as answer

Comment: nop. am getting error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException in C:\xampp\htdocs\opennGTS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php line 219:"

Comment: i have one doubt, my vehicleDetail.blade.php .  In my form, for the FromDate and To Date if i give type=date , then the value taken in the form of timestamp or normal date time format?

Comment: check my update. BTW that error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is gone ?

Comment: can you tell me the answer for this?

Comment: bcoz in table date and time stored as timestamp, so for checking query is working or not need to know this.

Comment: so for getting date in timestamp format , what should i do in my view blade.?